# What does Mail.app use to decide if an email is Junk Mail?

Tags: mail.app

Does anyone know how Mail decide junk message, in addition to trusting spamassassin header? For example, if I mark a message as junk, what criteria does Mail create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail.app uses more than one approach to junk mail.

- Some spam gets reported by other users.

  - You can forward your junk mail to spam@icloud.com and it gets added to Apple's filtering system.
- Mail servers sometimes mark messages as spam.

  - When a tool like spam assassin has marked an incoming message as junk, Mail.app respects that and passes it to the junk folder automatically.
- Mail.app also supports custom filters.

  - You can make your own filters that will direct junk mail into the junk folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the mail address that it is coming from to your contacts and the mail will no longer mark incoming mail from that address as Junk

Comment: This makes no attempt to answer the question being asked.